# openpyxl find cell's value based on another cell's value

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to iterate through a workbook using openpyxl(2.4.1) and python (2.7.1) and if two cells in a row have a specific value, I would like to append another cell's value in that row to a list. I believe I am loading too much into memory and I see nothing printing from mylist or the col3 value when I run the code below. (The workbook is pretty large 600k + rows):
Here is a sample of my code:

```
import openpyxl
import numpy
from openpyxl.utils import coordinate_from_string, column_index_from_string
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('P:\My_File.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb.active
mylist = []

for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == 'M123':
                location = str(cell.coordinate)
                col = column_index_from_string(location[0])
                col2 = col +1
                row2 = cell.row
                if cell(column=col2, row=row2).value == 'ATM':
                   location2 = str(cell.coordinate)
                   col = column_index_from_string(location[0])
                   col3 = col +1
                   print col3
                   row3 = cell.row
                   mylist.append(cell(column=col3, row=row3).value)
                   print mylist
```

This solution looks very messy and I believe there may be a cleaner way to do this, but this is my first time using openpyxl and after reading through other questions and the docs I am at a loss. Any suggestions/recommendations welcome.

Even when using offset, nothing prints. Eventually I get the following error. Is the issue that I'm loading too much into memory? Is there another way to iterate through?

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 225, in load_workbook
   ws_parser.parse()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 122, in parse
   dispatcher[tag_name](element)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 277, in parse_row
   self.parse_cell(cell)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 211, in parse_cell
   self.ws._cells[(row, column)] = cell
MemoryError
```

Comment: You might want to look using `cell.offset()`. If nothing is printing then you are not finding your signal values.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieClark. This does help and I think that I can structure the code to do what I need with offset, but I think the real issue may be the memory error I just added. Any thoughts?